what is the nature of compgen under zsh (as opposed to bash)?
I am in the process of replicating my development environment under Ubuntu from Macos.  A good deal of which consists of porting some utility zsh scripts from one machine to the other.
One recurring hurdle has been getting compgen to work.  I've researched posts like Bash completion does not work in ZSH/Oh-My-ZSH because COMP_WORDS is not an array
Bottom line:  so far, on Linux zsh, I am stuck with "compgen command not found".
I did use locate to find a compgen somewhere under bash completions, but calling it from zsh did not work.  Yes, compgen works, from bash.
Back on my mac, where compgen does work, I idly did a which compgen under zsh, which returned what looks like a function definition rather than a path.
which compgen :
(only first 10 lines copied to give you an idea)
compgen () {
    local opts prefix suffix job OPTARG OPTIND ret=1 
    local -a name res results jids
    local -A shortopts
    emulate -L sh
    setopt kshglob noshglob braceexpand nokshautoload
    shortopts=(a alias b builtin c command d directory e export f file g group j job k keyword u user v variable) 
    while getopts "o:A:G:C:F:P:S:W:X:abcdefgjkuv" name
    do
        case $name in
....

Meanwhile, under bash, which compgen returns nothing, presumably because it is a builtin.
So where does compgen under zsh come from?  Is it computed through the completion initialization in my ~/.zshrc ? quite possibly bashcompinit?:
(note:  below is from the macos ~/.zshrc, where compgen works)
# The following lines were added by compinstall
zstyle :compinstall filename '/Users/me/.zshrc'
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
# End of lines added by compinstallx

autoload -Uz bashcompinit
bashcompinit

#stop completions from $PATH on source, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/72710684
unset '_comps[source]'



why are you using bash? Me, and nearly all my friends, are using zsh on linux. It works just as well as bash.

I am still using zsh on linux, but… the scripts are huge, homegrown, and have lots of hardcoded paths, dependencies on things that had to be installed (ripgrep) as well as macos-only stuff like pbcopy and pbpaste.  compgen was an unexpected glitch in this.   Last, I actually can still run most of them under bash as well - cross shell compatibility is intriguing, to me, much like ANSI sql portability is.

Run from my linux bash:
$> type compgen
compgen is a shell builtin

from my linux zsh:
compgen is a shell function from /home/marcus/.oh-my-zsh/lib/completion.zsh

on a linux zsh on a "clean" installation with no .zshrc, you can find compgen defined as shell function, typically in /usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/bashcompinit. It is, after all, a "bash compability feature", and will be loaded when requested (see beginning of that file); autoload -Uz compgen if you need it.

You would need autoload -Uz bachcompinit and to actually run bashcompinit.
